# Deserializing json using asp.net libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, linq, json

I'm currently trying to deserialize the following JSON output in silverlight without javascript deserializer. I heard there's a way to do this using JsonArray and LINQ, but I can't quite figure it out.

```
{
    "Security": {
        "CIK": "0000789019",
        "Cusip": "594918104",
        "Symbol": "MSFT",
        "ISIN": "US5949181045",
        "Valoren": "951692",
        "Name": "Microsoft Corporation",
        "Market": "NASDAQGS",
        "CategoryOrIndustry": "TECHNOLOGY",
        "Outcome": "Success",
        "Message": null,
        "Identity": null,
        "Delay": 0
    },
    "StartDate": "7/1/2011",
    "EndDate": "7/6/2011",
    "Quotes": [{
        "Date": "7/5/2011",
        "Last": 26.03,
        "Open": 26.1,
        "LastClose": 26.02,
        "High": 26.15,
        "Low": 25.9,
        "ChangeFromOpen": -0.07,
        "PercentChangeFromOpen": -0.268,
        "ChangeFromLastClose": 0.01,
        "PercentChangeFromLastClose": 0.038,
        "Volume": 37803000,
        "SplitRatio": 1,
        "LastAdjusted": 26.03,
        "OpenAdjusted": 26.1,
        "LastCloseAdjusted": 26.02,
        "HighAdjusted": 26.15,
        "LowAdjusted": 25.9,
        "ChangeFromOpenAdjusted": -0.07,
        "ChangeFromLastCloseAdjusted": 0.01,
        "VolumeAdjusted": 37803000,
        "NotTraded": false,
        "Outcome": "Success",
        "Message": null,
        "Identity": null,
        "Delay": 0
    }, {
        "Date": "7/1/2011",
        "Last": 26.02,
        "Open": 25.93,
        "LastClose": 26,
        "High": 26.17,
        "Low": 25.84,
        "ChangeFromOpen": 0.09,
        "PercentChangeFromOpen": 0.347,
        "ChangeFromLastClose": 0.02,
        "PercentChangeFromLastClose": 0.077,
        "Volume": 52914500,
        "SplitRatio": 1,
        "LastAdjusted": 26.02,
        "OpenAdjusted": 25.93,
        "LastCloseAdjusted": 26,
        "HighAdjusted": 26.17,
        "LowAdjusted": 25.84,
        "ChangeFromOpenAdjusted": 0.09,
        "ChangeFromLastCloseAdjusted": 0.02,
        "VolumeAdjusted": 52914500,
        "NotTraded": false,
        "Outcome": "Success",
        "Message": null,
        "Identity": null,
        "Delay": 0
    }],
    "Outcome": "Success",
    "Message": null,
    "Identity": "Cookie",
    "Delay": 0.014001
}
```

What would be the best approach to doing something like this where I'm trying to extract the `Date` and `LastAdjusted` from the `Quotes` array and put each into their own arrays?

Here's how far I got to get the json into a stream:

```
downloader.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(downloader_OpenReadCompleted);
            downloader.OpenReadAsync(serviceUri);
        }

        void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Stream responseStream = e.Result;
                //add code here
            }
        }
```

Comment: Probably [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to parse it and Linq to select the information you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521239/deserializing-json-using-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code for Silverlight will take a JSON string, deserialize it to a "Listing" object and then loop through a list of quotes for the listing to extract the Date and LastAdjusted. Make sure to add a reference to System.ServiceModel.Web to your project in order to access the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) (MSDN) class.

**C#**

```
string json = // Your JSON string
Listing myListing = DeserializeJSON(json);
foreach (Quote quote in listing.Quotes)
{
    DateTime dt = quote.Date;
    Double lastAdjusted = quote.LastAdjusted;
}

public Listing DeserializeJSON(string json)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Listing));
        return (Listing)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

**Classes**

```
    public class Listing
    {
        public Security Security { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Security
    {
        public string CIK {get; set;}
        public string Cusip {get; set;}
        public string Symbol {get; set;}
        public string ISIN {get; set;}
        public string Valoren {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Market {get; set;}
        public string CategoryOrIndustry {get; set;}
        public string Outcome {get; set;}
        public string Message {get; set;}
        public string Identity {get; set;}
        public string Delay { get; set; }
    }

    public class Quote
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Double Last { get; set; }
        public Double Open { get; set; }
        public Double LastClose { get; set; }
        public Double High { get; set; }
        public Double Low { get; set; }
        public Double ChangeFromOpen { get; set; }
        public Double PercentChangeFromOpen { get; set; }
        public Double ChangeFromLastClose { get; set; }
        public Double PercentChangeFromLastClose { get; set; }
        public Double Volume { get; set; }
        public Double SplitRatio { get; set; }
        public Double LastAdjusted { get; set; }
        public Double OpenAdjusted { get; set; }
        public Double LastCloseAdjusted { get; set; }
        public Double HighAdjusted { get; set; }
        public Double LowAdjusted { get; set; }
        public Double ChangeFromOpenAdjusted { get; set; }
        public Double ChangeFromLastCloseAdjusted { get; set; }
        public Double VolumeAintdjusted { get; set; }
        public bool NotTraded { get; set; }
        public string Outcome { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Identity { get; set; }
        public int Delay { get; set; }
    }
```

You can learn more here: [JSON serialization and deserialization in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/JSON-serialization-and-deserialization-in-Silverlight.aspx)

Comment: I'm using silverlight so am not able to use this library. Is there another way to do this using LINQ?

Comment: @cfarm54: That certainly changes things. I have updated my answer so that you can deserialize a JSON object in Silverlight.

Comment: @cfarm54: Glad it worked.  Are you waiting for other answers before awarding the bounty?

Comment: No you will get it. I just can't issue it until 15 more hours

Answer (score 1):

Use Newtonsoft Json.net library to build a dictionary by your JSON. Then use LINQ.

Comment: I believe Json.NET is newtonsoft's JSON library.